# Transferring the button content between listboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I've created a listbox and filled it with data by binding it to the list I've created from XML file. I made it in such way, that every single entry is in form of a button.

Now I want to transfer the "Description" content of the button (upon clicking on it) to another listbox, with an addition of the current date. Is there an easy way to do it? Here is my XAML:

```
<ListBox Height="395" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,195,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410" AllowDrop="False" ItemsSource="{Binding activities}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Height="150" Width="400" Click="Act_Click">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<ListBox Height="491" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,105,0,0" Name="listBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436" ItemsSource="{Binding activities2}">
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding activities2}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                </Grid>                               
             </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here is how I read my file from XML:

```
namespace ReadXMLfromFile
{
   public class Activity
{
    public string Type { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public Activity(string type, string description)
    {
         Type = type;
         Description = description;
    }

    public static List<Activity> LoadActivities(XDocument doc)
    {
        return doc .Root
                   .Elements("Activity")
                   .Select(el => new Activity((string)el.Attribute("Type"),
                                            el.Value))
                   .ToList();                 
    }

    public static List<Activity> LoadActivities()
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (store.FileExists("Activities.xml"))
            {
                 using (var stream = store.OpenFile("Activities.xml",
                                                    FileMode.Open))
                 {
                     return LoadActivities(XDocument.Load(stream));
                 }
            }
        }
        // No user file... load the default activities
        return LoadActivities(XDocument.Load("Assets/Activities.xml"));        
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
var activities = (List<Activity>)listbox1.ItemsSource;
var myObject = (Activity)listbox1.SelectedItem;
activities.Remove(listbox1.SelectedItem);
myObject.Date = DateTime.Now; //to provide your last request(add the current date)
var activities2 = (List<Activity>)listbox2.ItemsSource;
if(activities2 == null)
{ 
    activities2 = new List<Activity>(); 
    listbox2.ItemsSource = activities2;
}
activities2.Add(myObject);
```

To be sure that the ListBox update their items do

```
listbox1.ItemsSource = null;
listbox1.ItemsSource = activities;
```

and

```
listbox2.ItemsSource = null;
listbox2.ItemsSource = activities2;
```

or simply use `ObservableCollection<Activity>` instead of `List<Activity>` and the ListBoxes should automatically update their items.

**EDIT**: fixed ItemTemplate for second ListBox

```
<ListBox Height="395" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,195,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410" AllowDrop="False" ItemsSource="{Binding activities}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Height="150" Width="400" Click="Act_Click">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<ListBox Height="491" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,105,0,0" Name="listBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436" ItemsSource="{Binding activities2}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Height="150" Width="400">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button>                          
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This looks promising. However I am getting a `NullReferenceException was unhandled` from `activities2.Add(myObject);` line. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You must replace MyObjectType with your object type

Comment: I'm aware of that. I changed it to `List<Activity>` since that is my list but it still throws the exception. I updated the question with the way I create a list, hope that will help

Comment: That works a little better, something displays on listbox2. However all I'm getting there after one press of a button is a long list of `ReadXMLfromFile.Activity`.

Comment: Are you sure you have the same ItemTemplate in both Listboxes

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. I didn't make ItemTemplate for 2nd listbox. Should I also bind listbox2 to the "activity" list in order for it to work?

Comment: if you bind the listbox you should bind it to activities2

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't work. I edited question with listbox2. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not sure how it's supposed to be.

Comment: I've seen your edit and now proper data is displayed. However now it's loading full list of activities from listBox1 instead of just a button I click.

Comment: Full list or full details?

Comment: Full list. Every description and type that was in the list activities. Just like in listbox1.

Comment: So what do you want to keep Type or Description?

Comment: I want to keep only description. But the bigger issue is the fact, that the code is just copying the whole list from listbox1 to listbox2 and not just one entry.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest binding the SelectedItem on your Listbox to a instance of an activity and when that property changes check to see if the description associated with that item has already been added to your second list and if not, then add it.